# C#/WPF: Display Images like a LightBox in jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, wpf, lightbox

Did anyone ever try to create a jQuery "LightBox"-Like "Popup" (WPF UserControl) for displaying Images?
See this page for an example: http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a site that appears to have done it, but it is only version 0.5 and might change dramatically before 1.0: 
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/#

This should be what you're looking for, and here is a sample of their code to implement:

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
});
```

I hope this helps,

### Thanks!

---

EDIT:

Sorry that I didn't fully understand what you ment in version one of your question.  Here is an updated answer (with code / source) to your question.

First I created a control that will act as a modal dialog box that grays everything out in the background.  Then I added the ability to put a picture in there, with added ability to have a comment with each picture.   Here are images of the final product:

First Image Loaded: 
[First Image Loaded http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/8941/firstpictureopen.jpg](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/8941/firstpictureopen.jpg)

Second Image Fading In: 
[Second Image Fading In http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/3172/secondpicturefading.jpg](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/3172/secondpicturefading.jpg)

Second Image Loaded: 
[Second Image Loaded http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/5404/secondpictureopen.jpg](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/5404/secondpictureopen.jpg)

I also added animations to resize the images like the Lightbox project does.  I added the ability to have a forward and back buttons, accelerator keys, forward and back arrow control, and escape to exit.  I think I've captured what you're looking for in this control.

As usual, I've uploaded the full source code to [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/stackoverflow-answers-by-scott/) for your download.

The direct link to the zip file is here:
http://stackoverflow-answers-by-scott.googlecode.com/files/1755872.zip

I hope this helps,

### Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Scott for the answer, but what I'm looking for is a WPF UserControl do to the same :-) Btw, at following page is a pretty solid jQuery script: http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#download

Comment: I gotcha, I am sorry that I mis-read.  I will get you an example (source) on a control that can do this.  :-)  Give me a little bit and I'l update my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate, that'd be great! I finished the the lightbox UserControl with Ray Burns idea, but it'd love to know how you'd do it. Cheers

Comment: I got it done, too bad I didn't get it done before you accepted Ray's answer. :-(  Maybe if it's a good enough answer you could switch it.. ;-)

Comment: Nice, works like a charm ;) Thanks Scott - hope this might help anyone else too.

Comment: Incredibly useful control, I borrowed it and rewrote it based off a ContentControl so I could stuff whatever I want inside the lightbox.  Now I have a perfect way to handle views/controls that I want to be application modal.

Comment: @vfilby - Thanks.  If it is still similar code and you wanted to, I could make you a contributer to the Google code project and you could upload the patch. :)  Thanks.

Comment: Ya @vfilby I'd like to see that too. @Scott. Good work, now I need to understand it.

Answer (score 4):

Duplicating the functionality you linked to is absolutely trivial in WPF.  Just:

1. Create a `UserControl` with a single `ItemList` property of type `IEnumerable<ImageSource>`
2. Add a `Popup` to the `UserControl`
3. Add a `Grid` to the `Popup` that lays out the LightBox the way you want, including panels for the `Image`, `TextBlock`, and `Button`
4. Add a `StoryBoard` that is triggered by the `Loaded` event that animates the changes.
5. Use an `EventTrigger` to set the `Popup`'s `IsOpen` property to false when the button is clicked
6. Bind the `Image.Source` to `{Binding ItemList/}` to show the current item in the ItemList
7. Add a `Background="Transparent"` rectangle to each side of the `Grid` that runs code-behind to change the current item in `ItemList`
8. Optionally also repeat the `BeginStoryboard` when changing the current item